# How to define a type dependent on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that has methods that will return `Eigen::Matrix` types. However, when these will be 1x1 matrices, I want to just return `double`, as treating scalars as `Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1>` is a bit nasty. Essentially, I want something like this:

```
template <int rows, int cols>
class foo
{
    using my_type = ((rows == 1 && cols == 1) ? double : Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols>); 
};
```

However, this (unsurprisingly) doesn't work. How can I create the equivalent of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::conditional_t<cond, TThen, TElse>`:

```
template <int rows, int cols>
class foo
{
    using my_type = std::conditional_t<rows == 1 && cols == 1, double, Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols>>;
};
```

If you don't yet have `std::conditional_t<>`, you might try `std::conditional<>::type` (with `typename` prefix).